# How to get column description using PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

How to get column description using PDO? AS far as i understood fetchColumn and getColumnMeta does not return description field, which is part of MySQL database table.

I would like to write code as general as possible, thus i use PDO, which connects to all possible databases. Most probably description field is not available in all databases, thus there is no general function for retrieving it?

Comment: So - you really never use using neither auto increment nor even LIMIT in your queries, when working with mysql database?

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
$table_fields = $dbh->query("DESCRIBE tablename")->fetchAll();
```

It will return you all the column names of the table . 
Or if you want it MySQL's side, you can try :

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM <table_name> WHERE Field = ?
```

`+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+`

Comment: He said he need NOT only column names. Yet it's mysql-specific command, I believe.

Comment: I do not ask about column names. I ask about column description, which is separate field in MySQL tables. I could not found how to get value of this field using PDO.